# How to pick only today and tomorrow jsonarray data by Date & Time and put in list view adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist, android-listview

here my jsonArray data like:

```
[{"LeadId":4,
 "CoreLeadId":0,
 "CompanyId":7,
 "AccountNo":"5675",
 "ScheduleOn":"2015-05-11T00:00:00"},
{"LeadId":7,
 "CoreLeadId":2,
 "CompanyId":8,
 "AccountNo":"sample string 4",
 "ScheduleOn":"2015-12-01T15:04:23.217"}]
```

i want to pick only today and tomorrow jsonarray dateandtime(ScheduleOn) and put into listview. below i side i send snnipt of my code where i set adapter. i retrieve data from database. Please help me.

```
   JSONArray jsonArray = dpsFunctionFlow.getAllServiceDetail("1");
   listItemService = new Gson().fromJson(jsonArray.toString(),
        new TypeToken<List<AppointmentInfoDto>>() {
        }.getType());
    mAdapter = new AdapterAppointment(getActivity(), listItemService);
    listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

i also want only upcoming list according time. and if possible so please give how to find today and tomorrow date and time yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS 
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Crate a new list with a filter.

```
listItemService.get(position).getScheduleOn().startwith(DateofTodayorTomorrow)
Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();      
    c.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());      
    String dateOfToday=c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);     
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);        
    String dateOfTomorrow=c.get(Calendar.YEAR)+"-"+(c.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1)+"-"+c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Comment: THANKS but i also want only upcoming list according time. and if possible so please give how to find today and tomorrow date and time yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS

Comment: Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();

Answer (score 0):

You can set a date filter in your custom arraylist adapter and achieve perfect results

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Sample {

    @SerializedName("LeadId")
    @Expose
    private Integer LeadId;
    @SerializedName("CoreLeadId")
    @Expose
    private Integer CoreLeadId;
    @SerializedName("CompanyId")
    @Expose
    private Integer CompanyId;
    @SerializedName("AccountNo")
    @Expose
    private String AccountNo;
    @SerializedName("ScheduleOn")
    @Expose
    private String ScheduleOn;

    /**
     * @return The LeadId
     */
    public Integer getLeadId() {
        return LeadId;
    }

    /**
     * @param LeadId The LeadId
     */
    public void setLeadId(Integer LeadId) {
        this.LeadId = LeadId;


    public Integer getCoreLeadId() {
        return CoreLeadId;
    }

    public Integer getCompanyId() {
        return CompanyId;
    }

    public String getAccountNo() {
        return AccountNo;
    }

    public String getScheduleOn() {
        return ScheduleOn;
    }
}
```

Add in the arraylist
specific which you want remove;